# Is it bad practice to apply a class attribute to an Angular component element?

Tags: css, angular

I don't often see examples where people put class names (class attributes) onto the actual Angular component like so:

```
<app-my-list class="list"></app-my-list>
```

One would do this when classes matter in that scope (so that class need not be inside the component's Sass file), or if they are related to elements around them as in a Flexbox flex-container/flex-child relationship:

```
<app-parent class="flex-container">
    <app-child class="flex-item"></app-child>
</app-container>
```

Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR - Not necessarily.

Following the principle of encapsulation, if the class affects the internal styling of the component, it'd probably be better to pass a variable to the component and let it determine its own styling. However, if like in your example, it's a bigger layout class, then it's actually a better practice to use a class like you're doing, because the component doesn't need to know about the layout.

Also, in order to not repeat yourself, I'm assuming this class does things that are special to certain instances of this component, and not all of them. If you're adding the same class to every single component instance, you'd be breaking the rule of "don't repeat yourself", which would be a bad practice.